# Displaying colors of very narrow rectangles in matplotlib's bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot data in matplotlib that has a very wide x axis range. I have two sets of data, that I would like to be distinguishable via two colors. However, the rectangles used in the standard bar plot are so narrowed that the colors don't display. Here's the code I'm using:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.bar(plotreal,plotabundance,color='#330000') #first data (x,y,color)
ax1.bar(xlist,ylist,color='#9999FF') #second set of data (x,y,color)
ax1.set_xlabel() #some axis labeling
ax1.set_ylabel() #some axis labeling
ax1.set_title() #some title labeling
plt.savefig('chart of '+str(counter)+'.png') #some more parameters
```

The data in the second set may overlap with that of the first (having the same points), and I would like its color to show whenever that is the case. I am interested in keeping this display format where each point is displayed as a line/rectangle, just add colors to the lines/rectangles.

Even though I tried making contrasting colors of the two data sets it's still impossible to distinguish that the second set in this example contained only 4 coordinates and the first set contained the rest.

[image: sample data]

(If anyone's curios, this is output data from a mass spectrometer)

Is there another graph type or parameters that I'm missing that I can use to remedy this color problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried setting `edgecolor='none'`? you could also increase the `width` of the bars.

Comment: No I didn't, but yes it works! using both no edge color and setting the width to 20  made thick enough distinguishable rectangles

Answer (score 2):

The edge colour is set by a different parameter  (default=black). Your bars are too small to see the fill colour so it looks black since the edge stays the same size!

To fix, `add edgecolor=...`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.bar(plotreal,plotabundance,color='#330000',edgecolor='#330000') #first data (x,y,color,edgecolor) 
ax1.bar(xlist,ylist,color='#9999FF',edgecolor='#9999FF') #second set of data (x,y,color,edgecolor)
ax1.set_xlabel() #some axis labeling
ax1.set_ylabel() #some axis labeling
ax1.set_title() #some title labeling
plt.savefig('chart of '+str(counter)+'.png') #some more parameters
```